# Java: how to calculate number of days from the beginning of time (with time zones)

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I want to calculate the number of days from the "beginning of time" to a current date. This could be easily achieved with a simple calculation (timestamp / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000 = daysFromBeginningOfTime) but the twist is that i need to be aware of time zones as well. The timestamp is the same everywhere in the world but when you parse it with the proper time zone then it reflects the differences between locations so using just the timestamp doesn't work and i don't want to handle all the time zone transitions myself.

**Example**:
if it's 23:30 in London and the day number is 18843 then in Amsterdam it's 0:30 and the day number should be 18844.

I looked at `joda.time` but didn't really find what i was looking for.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `new DateTime(0)` doesn't give "the beginning of time" - it gives "the unix epoch". Those are very different things.

Comment: You need to parse the date to an UTC timestamp. This would give you the consistent (and correct) result 18843 in your example. Look, it is not the case that - at any point in time - the epoch is 1 day further apart in Amsterdam than in London.

Comment: What do you consider to be "the beginning of time"?

Comment: Midnight on 1-Jan-1970, of course.

Comment: I was seven in 1970 - I don't remember hearing a really big bang.

Comment: Oh, it happened.  I think Richard Nixon had a hand in suppressing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears due to a wrong initial assumption, I think.

The argument the OP makes in his example is not correct. No matter what the clock shows in London or Amsterdam, the time difference to the start of the epoch is - at every point of time  - independent of where you are in the world.

Hence, the solution is to parse a given input date to an UTC timestamp and proceed as before.

Comment: Not at the speed relative to Greenwich we are considerng ... :)

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring the point that zero is not "the beginning of time" ... and that the actual time point for the beginning of time is probably unknowable ...)

Here's how to calculate the number of days since "the local-time UNIX epoch in a given timezone"<sup>1</sup>.

1. Get hold of the object that represents the local timezone.
2. Get the timezone's offset from the object
3. Convert it to milliseconds and add it to the current UTC time.
4. Calculate the day number as before.

---

<sup>1 - ... whatever that means.</sup>

Comment: Then you get the astonishing result that, depending on where you are, the epoch is magically further away than in different places. How comes?

Comment: @Ingo - I didn't say that the number is meaningful.  Ask the OP what he thinks it means, and why he wants to calculate it ...